# Next.js server rendered component window object

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js

I have a component who handles google login through js google api library.

```
export default class Index extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.onGoogleLoginSuccess = this.onGoogleLoginSuccess.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
          className="g-signin2"
          data-onsuccess="onGoogleLoginSuccess"
          data-theme="dark"
      />
  }
}
```

Since I am using express as my server, the component is being rendered in the server.

I put some logs and found that the render method is being called in the server and the componentDidMount is never called.

When next.js render the component in the server, is has any callback where I can put some code that will be executed in the client side? Where I would have access to the window object.

Comment: Is it never called (componentDidMount)?. According to next.js docs 'This lifecycle method will only be executed on the client.'. Did you check if the component is actually mounted in the client side?.

Comment: @PieroDivasto it is never called. Since the render method is being called in the server side, I think that the component is being mounted in the server side. My question is if there are any callback method where I can put my code that will be executed in the client side when the component is mounted in the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onComponentDidMount` is the correct place to access `window`, as the component is *only* mounted client-side (but render happens on both client & server).

Maybe that's not the full component, but it doesn't look like anything in your example exists for `this.onGoogleLoginSuccess`, since `this` would refer the the react instance in that context.

Comment: I haven't provided the implementation since it is not necessary for the example, but I have implemented the method. My code was working, but I added an express server to make some validations in the routes and now the onComponentDidMount is not being called anymore.

Comment: I found that the problem was being caused by an error in my js file, since Chrome couldn't parse the file, it stopped the execution and never executed the onComponentDidMount. I will accept your answer, since it was because of her that I was sure that the problem was not in next.js flow. Thanks for your help.